AuthenticationHandler's ChallengeAsync does not contain the failures
I've defined a custom AuthenticationHandler<T>. For testing purposes I implemented like this:
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("foo", new() {
        Items = {
            { "reason", "some message" }
        }
    });

When running in the debugger I see it call that method, and then immediately after it hits the HandleChallengeAsync method.  However, the properties parameter that HandleChallengeAsync receives has Items with a count of 0.  Why isn't it getting the property I defined?
I don't think I messed up the order of stuff in program.cs, but this is what I did:
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(PasetoToken.Scheme)
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, PasetoBearerHandler>(PasetoToken.Scheme, x => x.Validate());

builder.Services
    .AddAuthorization(x => x.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build());


var app = builder.Build();

app
    .UseRouting()
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseAuthorization()
    .UseExceptionHandler()
    .UseEndpoints(x => ...);


Can you share your whole AuthenticationHandler code?

Looks to me like PolicyEvaluator in the framework ignores Fail results in AuthenticateAsync, but then looks at it again in AuthorizeAsync.
There it returns a challenge result if authentication failed. I didn't look through the entire call graphs so some details might be missing here :)
Source code: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ee4a0e9801c4e1e673d0373e1c51a6790de174cc/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L42
Generally Challenge is responsible for setting response status code to 401 or setting up a redirect to a 3rd party login etc., so this flow seems logical.
As for why the parameters are not there, I think the PolicyEvaluator does not forward those to the challenge.

Thanks.  I nuked the challenge method and didn't return details on failure and now it's working as expected.  Strange they force you to put a reason on the Fail() call if they just completely ignore it.
